# Unir dois objetos em um com atributos condicionais em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, array

Estou com o seguinte dilema, preciso montar um objeto para enviar à uma `API rest`. Porém eu tenho dados que partem de uma variável. Pensei em várias maneiras de fazer isso mas não sei qual a certa, ou se nenhuma delas é a certa.

```
if (true){
  var obj = {
    "a": a,
    "b": b,
    "c": c,
    "d": d,
    "e": E,
    "f": F,
    "g": G,
  }
} else {
  var obj = {
    "a": a,
    "b": b,
    "c": c,
    "d": d,
    "e": H,
    "f": I,
    "g": J,
  }
}

// envio via ajax este obj para a API.
```

esta foi a primeira maneira da qual fiz. Mas achei que escrevo demais, se repararem, fiz isto pois alguns dos valores do objeto, eu irei pegar ou de uma variável já declarada, ou de outra. (neste objeto coloquei apenas 7 itens para não ficar muito extenso, mas no meu caso há mais de 20 itens, então o meu código fica ainda maior digitando o objeto duas vezes.

Após isso eu pensei em fazer da seguinta forma:

```
if (true){
 var x = E;
 var y = F;
 var z = G;
} else {
 var x = H;
 var y = I;
 var z = J;
}

var obj = {
  "a": a,
  "b": b,
  "c": c,
  "d": d,
  "e": x,
  "f": y,
  "g": z,
}

// envio via ajax este obj para a API.
```

No meu código, os items que são condicionais, são 5, de um total de aproximadamente 23. então fazendo desta maneira, consegui economizar umas linhas.

Mas ainda não estava contente, conheço a função push e a função concat (no meu projeto uso jquery e angular.js tbm).

Porém com essas funções, ele forma 1 array com 2 objetos. Há uma maneira de fazer esse "merge" que resulte em 1 array de 1 único objeto?

Comment: Você quer alterar os valores de um "ObjetoArray" com base um uma condição, é isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma outra maneira de se fazer o que precisa é a apresentada abaixo. Os pontos interessantes são:

1. Armazenar o retorno da condição em uma variável para, caso a condição mude com o tempo, basta alterar uma linha de código;
2. Utilizar o operador ternário nos atributos que possuem valor condicional, evitando que reescreva o objeto, ou parte dele, mais de uma vez;

```js
var condicao = true;

var obj = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3,
  "d": 4,
  "e": (condicao) ? 5 : -5,
  "f": (condicao) ? 6 : -6,
  "g": (condicao) ? 7 : -7
};

console.log(obj);
```

A saída do código, para a condição verdadeira:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3,
  "d": 4,
  "e": 5,
  "f": 6,
  "g": 7
}
```

Já, para a condição falsa:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3,
  "d": 4,
  "e": -5,
  "f": -6,
  "g": -7
}
```

> **Nota**: Utilizei os valores numéricos para poder reproduzir o resultado sem tem que definir inúmeras variáveis, porém, em sua aplicação, os valores dos atributos podem ser definidos a partir de variáveis naturalmente.

**Operador ternário**

O operador ternário possui a seguinte sintaxe:

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

Em que **condition** deve ser uma expressão, ou variável, booleana que é avaliada como`true` ou `false` e **expr1**, **expr2** são expressões com valores de qualquer tipo. A descrição do funcionamento é o seguinte: se *condition* for `true`, o operador retorna o valor de *expr1*, se não, retorna o valor de *expr2*.

Desta forma, ter um código `var x = a > 2? 1 : -1` seria o mesmo que ter:

```
if (a > 2) {
    x = 1;
} else {
    x = -1;
}
```

Só que com muito menos código e mais legível.

Comment: Em programação, se você sentir que está reescrevendo muito código, com certeza existe uma maneira mais prática de se obter o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Ótima explicação! Testei aqui e já funcionou, e com muito menos código! Obrigado amigo! :)